# How do I specify the correct xpath / css selector for drop down list in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to interact with a drop down list in Selenium and am currently getting having trouble in specifying the correct name / ID.

Xpath of the drop down list : //*[@id="post-2646"]/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s49UW.png)/div/div/div/p/select
URL of the drop down list: https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/select-dropdown-menu

My current code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import time
    
    PATH =r"C:\Users\hey\OneDrive\Python\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get("https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/select-dropdown-menu")
    
    mySelect = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[contains(@id,'post-2646')")))).click()

    mySelect.select_by_visible_text('Taiwan')
```

This is the elements inspection page:

[image]

I've tried various other names / tags but am still getting the following timeout error message:

[image]

From my research, it seems that I'm inputting the wrong id name of the dropdown list in this line of code but I can't seem to be able to pinpoint the correct name / id to be used.

```
 mySelect = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[contains(@id,'post-2646')")))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong xpath. use below xapth for dropdwon
and use select_by_value() method for selecting option
as per https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/select-dropdown-menu page
option value for taiwan is TWN.
xpath=//div[@rel-title='Select Country']//select

```
mySelect = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@rel-title='Select Country']//select')")))).click()

mySelect.select_by_value('TWN')

OR
 mySelect.select_by_visible_text('Taiwan, Province of China')
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I modified the xpath to the one specified in your answer but am still getting the timeout exception error message..

Comment: Put some wait there.  you can set implicit wait by writing driver.implicitly_wait(15)  or  set explicit wait.  for explicit wait refer this link https://www.techbeamers.com/selenium-webdriver-waits-python/